# Догадка, не совместимости версий, но чего ? Tensorflow и keras

Tags: python, python-3.x, keras, tensorflow

> File
> "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\tf_obj_detect\lib\site-packages\imageai\Detection\keras_retinanet\models\resnet.py",
> line 19, in 
> import keras   File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\tf_obj_detect\lib\site-packages\keras_*init*_.py",
> line 6, in 
> 'Keras requires TensorFlow 2.2 or higher. ' ImportError: Keras requires TensorFlow 2.2 or higher. Install TensorFlow via `pip install tensorflow`

При установке версии "2.2", появляется ошибка:

> ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement
> tensorflow (from versions: none) ERROR: No matching distribution found
> for tensorflow `C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\tf_obj_detect\lib\site-packages\keras\` или  `C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\tf_obj_detect`

powershell (ws code) пишет все установлено

Вопрос, версия чего не установлена? что нужно сделать?

Comment: `tensorwlof`... Опечатались.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/38896424